# Magento 2 theme broken reference on contact page displaying blank

Tags: xml, layout, frontend, magento2

I have an issue on FE on Magento 2 custom theme in contact page. Theme is based on original luma theme. When i open contact page in custom theme it is displaying blank, but in Luma theme it is working correct. I don't know where to start debugging. Only errors that i got is here.

```
[2016-05-18 08:34:06] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_40a98983867a1770682b48d9a0ad63441: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2016-05-18 08:34:06] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'contactForm' element cannot be added as child to 'content', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-05-18 08:34:06] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'captcha_page_head_components' element cannot be added as child to 'head.components', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
```

I also created in backend contactform templated and linked it to site.